# FileImporter SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, file-import, swiftui-fileimporter

I m experiencing something weird with my File Importer in SwiftUI.

Here is the code I´m using to invoke the file importer :

```
.fileImporter(isPresented: $showFilePicker, allowedContentTypes: [.data], onCompletion: { result in
    print(result)
})
```

The sheet with the importer shows up. However, it opens by default on "Recents" and I have no menu to navigate?

Image with no Menu

[image: Image with no Menu]

I can make the menu show up if I type something on the search bar and then press the "X" which clears the text, after that the menu will show up.

Menu shows up after clearing search bar

[image: Menu shows up after clearing search bar]

This is the wished style. With the menu. What am I missing?

Comment: Yes I did. I was hiding the menu programatically on another view which cause it to also be hidden on system views.

Comment: Could yo please, share the code where you were hiding the menu so I can check if I'm doing something similar?

Comment: Of course mate! UITabBar.appearance().isHidden = true , setting that to false fixed it for me